# Render table component with 500 rows block browser?

Tags: ember.js

I have a component which render 500+ data into a HTML table rows

It take almost 3 seconds to render and the browser is completed blocked.

I cannot use pagination because the client want it excel-like and it is a static site.

Is there a way to solve this issue? For example create a loading state before the component is rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess 500+ row does not fit to the screen (viewport), so you need to use a scroll.

There is an addon named `ember-in-viewport`. It gives you the ability of not rendering the component if it is not in viewport.

Here is a [sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ff373bcda86beefe0ca1a857eb27abff?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C). Change `my-component` to `my-proxy-component` in your `applicaiton.hbs` to see the effect.

Comment: I need them to render to position them. for exable go to element 100 and scroll to that position

Comment: In that case, you need to handle the scrolling. Not a big deal, see the [sample scrolling in here](https://ember-twiddle.com/2d2f7436bcb6d154a93f71d2554bc2f1?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

Comment: Thank you so much for all these samples. I will give a try.

Comment: @ykaragol man I needed something like this ages  ago you are awesome. Pls take this up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Don't render all the objects at once, just load what's visible inside your viewport. There are already different Ember addons doing exactly what you need.

Some addons you could use:

- [Vertical Collection](https://github.com/html-next/vertical-collection)
- [Ember Infinity](https://github.com/hhff/ember-infinity)
- [Ember Light Table](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-light-table)

P.S. Of course you could also create a component/addon yourself and use the [ember-in-viewport](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-in-viewport) addon @ykaragol suggested, but I think that's overkill in your situation.